# ReSharper - Saving settings to a file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, code-cleanup

How do I save **ReSharpers** settings to a file?

I need to share the settings among my co-workers, and it has to include formatting settings setup in VS as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In main menu open Resharper->Manage options. There you have got import/export settings. Or you can just apply settings for project and commit this file to repository.

Comment: I almost sure that yes. You can easy check this :)

Comment: Just tested it, and it was included in my `GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings` file, which is located in: `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny`.